# Tomcat8 Startup Error (spring-boot) : SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory (-Dnop)

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I deployed a web application using spring-boot in external Tomcat and got the startup error below.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from '-Dnop'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../.../../home/work/-Dnop (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)
```

To deploy my application in external Tomcat server, I made 3 changes.

Change 1> in Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Change 2> in pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Change 3> in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tested with different versions of spring-boot.

```
spring-boot 1.2.5 : no issue.
spring-boot 1.3.8 : has the issue.
spring-boot 1.4 : has the issue.
```

Can it be a bug of spring-boot or did I miss some configuration to deploy spring-boot in an external Tomcat server?
It would be appreciated, if you would help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. One of the reason it occurred is because there was no file at \conf\logging.properties of your Tomcat.

Anyway, the issue has been fixed starting from Spring Boot 1.4.3 cf https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/7639

Comment: I am so thankful for your attention and comments. Brilliant!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @claire my pleasure! I encountered the same bug a few weeks ago so I thought I may as well fix it in the process :)